# Accessing users data from Google play game services in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I wanted to implement Google Play game services to my Unity game to have leaderboards, achievements etc. How can I get the users data like name, date of birth etc.? And I am using Google Play game services unity plugin found here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access  their name by some function like this :

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.GetSelf().Displayname
```

but you can't access other persona information.

Comment: Any idea why this would't return anything?